# bundling and minification and async/await

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET WebForms Web-Site project and have been using bundling and minification for some time. Now that I am using Async/Await pattern in my javascript the minification part throws an error when it encounters "Async" in the code. Is there a solution for this that I am not aware of?

Comment: Not sure about your specifics, but: `async/await` is an advanced feature of JS/ES, and a process called "transpiling" is usually required. I belive all modern bundlers/minimizers have that feature, or you must find a tool that have it (I'm looking at you, Webpack! not the easiest choice tho). Or, you might need to specify a target for your bundler, like ES5, ES6, etc. Try next higher setting that is available to you (if that's the case, of course).

Comment: There is no such setting. I am talking about the bundling and minification that is part of Microsoft.ASPNet.Web.Optimization Nuget package which hasn't been updated since Feb 2014. What is the modern replacement for this?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help here because never worked with ASP.NET, and my reply was not specific, but rather general. That being said, modern replacement (not sure if this applies to ASP.NET) would be webpack or parcel. Don't know much about parcel, but webpack is a beast, and integrating it from scratch into existing project going to be a pain... Probably there are better options specifically for ASP.NET, let's wait for other stackoverflow people to share their knowledge?

Answer (score 0):

This still appears to be an open issue: https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/issues/311

Toward the bottom of the thread the user ndenkha offers a work around.

> What we ended up doing is removing the await from any HTTP method
>   calls, since the wire trip on the Controller side is async, it seems
>   to work. e.g.

```
async getUserStuff(userId) {
let userStuff = $.get(/UserConfig/GetUserStuff?userId=${userId});
return userStuff;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the work around. How will the javascript work if you remove the Await key word from code that needs it?

Comment: You might get a better answer in that github thread but from what I read, it doesn't sound like the Await keyword is actually needed in that scenario.

Comment: Well all my awaits are needed.